# Get current node within text selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, summernote

I'm attempting to get the node I'm standing at after selecting the text meaning if I have the following DOM structure:

```
<p>
   This is an example
   <span style="text-transform: uppercase">text in caps</span>
   some more text in here
</p>
```

When I select text in caps, i would like to get the node where this selection is. In this case, would be the `<span>` in case I select everything of course.

I know there's a library called rangy but I think it's kinda overkill for me to use it just to get these nodes, any other way to retrieve it?

This is how I implement it so far:

```
var select = window.getSelection();
if (select.rangeCount) {
   var $elem = $('<span>', {'style': 'text-transform: ' + type});
   var range = select.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
   var selectedNode = range.cloneContents().childNodes[0];
   var nodeHasStyle = !!(selectedNode.style && selectedNode.style.textTransform.length !== 0);

   if (nodeHasStyle) {
       // If it's the same as previous, just toggle it by resetting the node
       var currentStyle = selectedNode.style.textTransform;
       selectedNode.style.textTransform = currentStyle === type ? '' : type;
   }

   range.surroundContents(!nodeHasStyle ? $elem.get(0) : selectedNode);

   select.removeAllRanges();
   select.addRange(range);
```

But noticed `selectedNode` is not always correct. So whenever I do surroundContents, it adds a new span around the one that I should have gotten in the first place.

I'm working with summernote to toggle uppercase, lowercase text-transform over a range of selected text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you do not need to rely on other libraries first you need to get the selected text then find node which contained this text through xpath i.e

```
let text = window.getSelection().toString()
if (text) {
  let xpath = "//text()[contains(., '"+ text +"')]";
  let selectionNode = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
```

or you can use window selection i.e `window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode`

Comment: Thanks for replying. Wow, let me check that.

Comment: Mmm it's not working, it's returning some different DOM element from the document. Nothing related to the contenteditable i'm currently editing. I tried changing anchor to span because it's usually a span and returns some random span. It's weird because im passing as node context the paragraph i'm editing on.

Comment: sorry my mistake in that case you can use the generic xpath i.e:
xpath = "//text()[contains(., '"+ text +"')]";

Comment: It still returns any random text that contains that word even if it's css within style tags in the document, not the desired result. Also, let's say i highlight the word "content", it will search for any word "content" in my document and apply the uppercase/lowercase inline-styling... when i just want to only get the node i'm selecting on the RTE contenteditable. Bare in mind that i could have many "content" word in 1 single text as well... i just need the one i'm selecting atm.

Comment: i think you need window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode